Issue with npm install (node.exe) popups in VSCode, but not in admin mode
I have an issue where, on every startup of VSCode, or every file opening, I get popups from node.exe related to npm install. The multiple quick popups are annoying and only appear when I open VSCode in non-admin mode. When I run VSCode as administrator, the issue doesn't happen.
I tried uninstalling Node.js globally and reinstalling it again, but it didn't help.
What could be causing these popups to appear, and how can I prevent them from showing up every time I launch VSCode in non-admin mode?


I've seen this issue Visual studio code runs NPM outside integrated terminal before and the only solution was to run VSCode as administrator. However, this solution restricts me from using AutoHotkeys and update VSCode automatically.
Here is the solution I randomly found today:
check if node.exe isn't running as administrator, because this is most likely what's causing these node popups. Disable run as administrator in the properties of this file.


Remove unnecessary postinstall scripts.
Configure npm globally to avoid admin rights.
Clear npm Cache: Run npm cache clean --force.
Make sure the version is up to date
This might help resolve the issue.



I have no postinstalls in my projects.
I did npm config set prefix ~/.npm-global and echo '$env:PATH += ";$env:USERPROFILE\.npm-global\bin"' >> $PROFILE. Nothing changed.
Cleared the cache - no changes.
The Node version is up to date - v22.12.0, Npm - 10.9.2

